# Recursive grep for bash in cygwin

Tags: bash, grep

if i want an alias to do "rgrep pattern *" to search all files from my current location down through any sub directories, what is an alias for rgrep I can add to my bashrc file?

i would also like it to ignore errors and only report positive hits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for it to ignore errors (such as "Permission denied"), you'll probably need to use a function instead of an alias:

```
rgrep () { grep -r "${@}" 2>/dev/null; }
```

Comment: how would i modify this to make it also find directories? if I have a directory named "hi" and I want to do "rgrep hi *" from some upper level dir I want that hit to come up too

Comment: `grep` doesn't search for file or directory names, and there is no flag you can pass to make it do that.  It only looks at file _contents_.  You'd need to separately invoke a command like `find . -name` if you want results based on file/dir names to print.  It could go in the same function if you really want your weird rgrep thing to do both.

Comment: @Derek: As Walter said, `find` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
alias rgrep="grep -r"
```

This will only show 'positive hits', i.e. lines that contain the pattern you specify.

Small piece of advice, however: you might want to get used to just using `grep -r` directly. You'll then find it much easier if you ever need to use someone else's workstation, for instance!

**Edit:** you want to match patterns in file **names**, not in their contents (and also in directory names too). So how about this instead:

```
alias rgrep="find | grep"
```

By default, `find` will find all files and directories, so then it's just a case of passing that list to `grep` to find the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: I think this will miss directories named with my pattern, eh?